# When should I use "à moi" vs "me"?

Tags: pronoms, syntaxe

Example: I want to say in French "You give to me".

Should I say "Tu me donnes" or "Tu donnes à moi"?

Another way to phrase the question would be, can both "me" and "à moi" act as an indirect object to the sentence?
When should I use each one and why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do verbs that take "à lui" instead of pre-verbal "lui" all have specific qualities?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/52130/do-verbs-that-take-%c3%a0-lui-instead-of-pre-verbal-lui-all-have-specific-qualiti)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, both *me* and *à moi* can act as indirect objects, and *me* can act as both a direct and indirect object: *Tu me donnes* might mean 'You give me (to someone)' or 'You give to me (something)', e.g.: *Tu me donnes aux flics* or *Tu me donnes la main*, *Tu me donnes à manger*.

*Tu donnes à moi* is odd but is common with a direct object pronoun before the verb: *Tu *le* donnes à moi*: 'You give it to me', it emphasizes the indirect object, the recipient here. The form *Tu me le donnes* is more common and neutral.

You can also use both forms at the same time, e.g.: *Tu me le donne à moi ?* (for example to double check you correctly hear it) or *Tu lui donne à elle !* (to clarify it is not *à lui* but *à elle* or to emphazise your disagreement.)